# Can't Get CloudKit to Authenticate (Using Javascript and a Server-to-Server Key)

Tags: javascript, cloudkit

I'm trying to use Apple's `cloudkit.js` file to make a server-to-server connection to CloudKit.  However, despite messing with the config for several hours, I can't seem to get CloudKit to consider my request valid.

My config logic is pretty straightforward:

```
const privateKeyFile = `${__dirname}/eckey.pem`;
const keyID = '*some key ID*';

const config = {
  containers: [
    {
      containerIdentifier: 'iCloud.com.*someNameSpace.someProject*',
      environment: 'development',
      serverToServerKeyAuth: { keyID, privateKeyFile },
    },
  ],
  services: {
    fetch,
  },
};
CloudKit.configure(config);

const container = CloudKit.getDefaultContainer();
container.setUpAuth();
```

However, that final `container.setUpAuth();` always results in `{"uuid":"*some UUID*","serverErrorCode":"AUTHENTICATION_FAILED","reason":"no auth method found"`.

I've even tried adding `console.log` lines inside `cloudkit.js` itself to log what gets sent to CloudKit, and it does appear to have the correct headers:

```
_host: 'https://api.apple-cloudkit.com',
_path: '',
_params: { ckjsBuildVersion: '17AProjectDev77', ckjsVersion: '1.2.0' },
_headers:
 { 'content-type': 'text/plain',
   'X-Apple-CloudKit-Request-ISO8601Date': '2017-03-03T00:52:48Z',
   'X-Apple-CloudKit-Request-KeyID': '*my key*',
   'X-Apple-CloudKit-Request-SignatureV1': '*what looks like a valid signature*' },
_body: undefined,
_method: 'GET',
_wsApiVersion: 1,
_containerIdentifier: '*my container identifier*',
_containerEnvironment: 'development',
_databaseName: 'public',
_apiModuleName: 'database',
_responseClass: [Function: a],
_apiEntityName: 'users',
_apiAction: 'current' }
```

I've lost hours to trying to grok the (minnified) `cloudkit.js` file, and I still have no idea why things aren't working.  Any help at all, even just debugging ideas, would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I'm sure I have access to the CloudKit container because when I go to `https://icloud.developer.apple.com/dashboard/` it's there in the URL `https://icloud.developer.apple.com/dashboard/#*myContainerId*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there are two (or more?) versions of `cloudkit.js`.  Because Apple goes out of their way *not* to use NPM like every other company on the planet (even though they use it in their CloudKit instructions), and because the documentation for server-to-server CloudKit connections is sort of an afterthought, it's very easy to wind up with the web version when you really want the Node one.  And (unless you're *really* good at reading minified code) there's no way to tell just by looking at it.

It turns out I had somehow gotten the web-focused version of `cloudkit.js`, and I needed the Node-focused version.  After I repeated the process listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CloudAtlas/Listings/Node_node_client_s2s_README_md.html) I got that version and was finally able to get my CloudKit code working.

Moral of the story: if the company providing your API libraries is too stupid/arrogant/whatever to use `npm` like everyone else, you have to be very careful not to shoot yourself in the foot.  Be certain you're following the Node-specific instructions linked above.

Comment: This helped me with a similar issue because I did not know that the second version of CloudKitJS was not an upgrade, at least that's what I think after reading the link to the Apple docs. Switched from `<script src="https://cdn.apple-cloudkit.com/ck/2/cloudkit.js" async></script>` back to `<script src="https://cdn.apple-cloudkit.com/ck/1/cloudkit.js" async></script>` and it fixed my trouble.

Comment: I have been battling this for **DAYS** and almost gave up. Downloading the example you pointed out, and getting the right version of CloudKit JS has been super helpful. I also discovered a subtle, but very important line of code needed: `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";` My server rejected all requests without that. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, it works only by 1st version of ClouKit JS, but asks for authentication even on Public Database.

I still got the error below, but it is working now. Does someone know how to solve it? After expanding the error message on console tool, it shows a object with redirectURL and uuid..

"XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: https://api.apple-cloudkit.com/database/1/iCloud.com.kueiapp…311e194dee13...a706
Line Number 1, Column 1:"